# How to get author name in the content for an abstract included in the article?

Tags: table-of-contents, content-replication

I am preparing one souvenir for the conference, which we are going to conduct in the next month..

I am including the contents in the following way..

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\address#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\email#1{\texttt{#1}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}

\section{The title of the Paper-1}


\aut{Here type the author name}\\
\insti{Name of the institute}\\
\address{fill the institute address here\\
         If you want second line}\\
\email{email@yahoo.com}\\


\begin{abstract}
Type your Abstract here...

\end{abstract}

\section{The title of the Paper-2}


\aut{Here type the author name}\\
\insti{Name of the institute}\\
\address{fill the institute address here\\
         If you want second line}\\
\email{email@yahoo.com}\\


\begin{abstract}
Type your Abstract here...

\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

### Question:

1. I need the author name in my content list..
2. If I want institute, and address also in my content along with their title, what should I do?

Currently my output is,
[image]

I want author name followed by their title in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the amended code, this will append contents given in `\aut` and `\insti` to the TOC.

```
\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hskip1pc#1}}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hskip1pc#1}}
```

[image]

And, these revised command will remove the page number as well.

```
\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}
```

Comment: If I dont want the page number for author name and institute, what should I do..@Sunilkumar

Comment: Yes you are right, the page numbers are not required there.  I have updated my answer by adding the revised codes at the end.

Comment: But that dots also I dont want..How I can do that??@sunilkumar

Comment: Just give: `\makeatletter \renewcommand\@dotsep{300}`

Comment: its giving some syntax error..@sunilkumar

Comment: Unable to help you without seeing what the error you got.  Anyway, my preamble looks like: `\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@dotsep{300}

\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}

\def\address#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\email#1{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32779/discussion-between-sunilkumar-ks-and-david).

Comment: I got it..It because of the position of the command `\makeatletter \renewcommand\@dotsep{300} ` .. Now working nicely.. thanks a lot...@sunilkumar